# How do I build a double penny per day form in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I get this for loop to display double the number of pennies every day?

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int days = Int32.Parse(txtNumberOfDays.Text);
        int totalPay = 0;
        int pennies = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
        {
            totalPay += pennies;
            pennies = pennies * 2;
           
        }

        txtTotalPennies.Text = totalPay.ToString();
    }
```

The code below is my first attempt at this problem and I think it works correctly. Can you tell me if this code is correct?

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Double NumberOfDays = Convert.ToDouble(txtNumberOfDays.Text);
        Double TotalPennies = 1;

        for (Double i = 1; i <= NumberOfDays; i++)
        {
            TotalPennies = Math.Pow(2, NumberOfDays - 1);
        }

        txtTotalPennies.Text = TotalPennies.ToString();
    }
```

EDITED - Is the below code correct?

```
 private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int days = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfDays.Text);
            int totalPay = 0;
            int pennies = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
            {
                totalPay = pennies;
                pennies = pennies * 2;
               
            }

            txtTotalPennies.Text = totalPay.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Your pennies increase 1,2,4,8,16 etc. But you add it to totalPay and display that: (0+1=)1,(+2=)3,(+4=)7,(+8=)15 etc

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert string to int

```
Convert.ToInt32(string str);
```

so

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int days = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfDays.Text);
    int totalPay = 0;
    int pennies = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
    {
        totalPay += pennies;
        pennies = pennies * 2;
       
    }

    txtTotalPennies.Text = totalPay.ToString();
}
```

Comment: With this code the pennies still do not double every day. Day 1 = 1, Day 2 = 3, and Day 3 = 7

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int days = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfDays.Text);
            int totalPay = 0;
            int pennies = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
            {
                totalPay = pennies;
                pennies = pennies * 2;
               
            }

            txtTotalPennies.Text = totalPay.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid loops by correct computing a power and just use that:

```
private int Pow(int x, int y)
{
    if (y < 0)
        throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    if (x == 0 && y == 0)
        throw new System.ArgumentException();
    if (y == 0)
        return 1;
    if (y == 1)
        return x;
    return x * Pow(x, y - 1);
}

private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTotalPennies.Text =
        int.TryParse(txtNumberOfDays.Text, out int days)
        ? $"{Pow(2, days)}"
        : "Invalid";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void Main()
{
 decimal total = 0M;
      int index=1;        
      for(int i=1;i<=int.MaxValue;i*=2)
      {       
          if(index==30) break;
          index++;
           total = ((decimal)2 * 0.01M)* i;
           Console.WriteLine(total);
      }
}
```

Comment: This is awfully coded. There are so many things here that I would reject in a code review.